# release an application sqlite using c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have an external SQLite file in my debug project c#. I try to release my application but my SQLite doesn't include in my release projects.

but my SQLite still not include in my release projects. how to include external SQLite to my release project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> external SQLite file in my debug project c#

If you have an external file - in general - and you want to include it into your project output, perform the following steps:

- put the file in a dedicated project folder (not required but helps when using version control)
- include the file into the project
- mark the file as "Content" and set "Copy To Output Directory" to: "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer"

[image: Example]

And the alternative option:

[image]

Comment: Better you select option Copy if Newer in place of Always

Comment: @viveknuna: did you read the text? ;-) I'll shall add the alternative image XD